# Cannot export Interface in Typescirpt - the requested module does not provide an export named Settings

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I am trying to export/import an interface in Typescript but I am getting this error, I am not sure what I am doing wrong here

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/src/types/settings.ts' does not provide an export named 'Settings'

In my **types/settings.ts** I have this

```
export interface Settings {
    activeUser: number
}
```

And I import it like this

```
import { Settings } from '@/types/settings'
```

And here is my **tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "baseUrl": "./src/",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"],
    },
    "sourceMap": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom"],
    "isolatedModules": false
  },

  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue"]
}
```

I am using Vue/Vite with Typescript

Answer (score 3):

It is weird that `npm run build` will work fine, but `npm run dev` will throw SyntaxError.

I was forced to use `import type { ...` which in consequence also required same touch for `Ref` from `vue`.

Workaround was posted on GitHub for Vite [issue 731](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/731#issuecomment-678625456)

Answer (score 2):

Most likely a problem of importing interfaces without explicitly marking them as type. [Vite requires isolatedModules being true](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#isolatedmodules) which in turn [requires](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#isolatedModules) handling interface this way:

```
interface IFoo { bar: string; }
export type { IFoo };
```

Keep in mid, if you re using barrel files (index.ts) that look like this:

```
export { IFoo } from './foo';
```

you should convert them to be like this instead:

```
export * from './foo';
```

or like this

```
import type { IFoo } from "./foo";
export type { IFoo };
```

Another dirty option is to set skipLibCheck to true in tsconfig.json, which will reduce your type strictness though.

Answer (score 0):

Entries in `paths` are resolved relative to `baseUrl`. Try this:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

… or this:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src/",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this , maybe the problem will be solved .

```
import type {StateType}  from "@/models/app.models";
```